# jQuery countdown out-of-alignment format

Tags: jquery, html, countdown

I tried to implement a countdown timer to my aspx page but I got this view: [image: countdown timer view in aspx page]
when I place it in an empty page (html or aspx), it runs correctly. But when I place it under a form structure in .net, it crashes as indicated in the capture.

Here is my countdown block:

```
<div id="countdown_dashboard">
    <div class="dash weeks_dash" style="display: none">
        <span class="dash_title">week</span>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
    </div>

    <div class="dash days_dash" style="display: none">
        <span class="dash_title">day</span>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
    </div>

    <div class="dash hours_dash">
        <span class="dash_title">hour</span>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
    </div>

    <div class="dash minutes_dash">
        <span class="dash_title">minute</span>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
    </div>

    <div class="dash seconds_dash">
        <span class="dash_title">second</span>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- Countdown dashboard end -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('#countdown_dashboard').countDown({
            targetDate: {
                'day': 10,
                'month': 6,
                'year': 2013,
                'hour': 11,
                'min': 0,
                'sec': 0
            }
        });

        $('#email_field').focus(email_focus).blur(email_blur);
        $('#subscribe_form').bind('submit', function () { return false; });
    });
</script>
```

Imported files in head tags are:

```
<%--<script src="jQuery-countdown/js/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>--%>
    <script src="jQuery-countdown/js/jquery.lwtCountdown-1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery-countdown/js/misc.js"></script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="jQuery-countdown/style/main.css"/>
```

Note: I commented out the first one because it effects the form tag content badly.

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Can you show us your CSS?

Comment: I found that the import of: <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" /> makes it ruin